# mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt trigger watchdog

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, watchdog

During a strong file I/O application, the Pi regular crashes.

```
mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt - cmd25.
mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt - cmd12.
mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt - cmd13.
mmcblk0: error -110 sending status command, retrying
```

...

```
Message from syslogd@pippin at Mar 8 19:03:21 ...
 kernel:[  735.850687] journal commit I/O error
```

...

```
[  1301.251534] journal commit I/O error
```

using Raspbian "wheezy" 2013-02-09-wheezy-raspbian.zip (and updated)

Different Raspberry Pis and different SD-Cards (same series) cause the same problem. I test other cards in a few days. I remember a different card (class 6 instead 10) would have held out for a week already.

memtest 480 2 is okay
Measured Voltage on TP1 and TP2: 4.87V
Tried with and without USB-Hub with a power supply.

Is there a way to tell the watchdog, the system (mmc0) crashed?

A dirty hourly cron execute /sbin/init 6 does not work in this case. Reverse ssh neither.

I know I am not alone with this problem: http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards But I can't test hundred cards.

I want to play it safe and fix it automatically if need (restart is a acceptable solution for me).

By the way: Restart the Pi every hour just delay the problem. Sometimes it occurs after 2 minutes.

Thank you for any help. Kind regards from Berlin

Answer (score 1):

I was getting these errors on bootup - however not during normal operation.
My problem was resolved when I switched from a TV (using HDMI cable) to a monitor (using HDMI to DVI cable). And also when I swapped to a different keyboard.
If I unplugged the original keyboard before bootup ( to Raspbian GUI), and then plugged keyboard in after bootup, I would not have the issue.
So I personally think the problem in my case related to excessive current draw on RPi.
And from what you have explained - I think it might be the same in your case.

My original keyboard was one of those flexible rollup keyboards.
I swapped to a simple no-frills keyboard - (and to monitor) and issue resolved.

Not sure if this helps you, but hopefully will help others.

Comment: Until the appearance of the error no monitor and no Tastur was connected. I no longer have the 
Raspberry Pi. Changed to Zotac Barebones. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what's the matter behind the issue, but I got same error that caused a stucked system on arch linux running on a raspberry pi 2 as soon as i had updated to linux kernel 4.1.9-1-armv7h.

To solve, I just did a downgrade to 4.1.6-2-armv7h and the issue disappeared.